# How to plot specific columns in multiple dataframes in a list?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, syntax, lapply

Sorry for this basic question. I thought I'd be able to solve this but I really could not figure out the syntax. I am quite new to R. Hopefully someone could explain to me how to do this.

I have a list of data frames with data and I wish to plot them.

```
df_list <- list(
  `1.3.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Alex",    175L,     75L,
      "Gerard",    180L,     85L,
      "Clyde",    179L,     79L
    ),
  `2.2.A` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Missy",    175L,     75L,
      "Britany",    180L,     85L,
      "Sussie",    179L,     79L
    ), 
  `1.1.B` = 
    tibble::tribble(
      ~Person, ~Height, ~Weight,
      "Luke",    175L,     75L,
      "Alex",    180L,     85L,
      "Haley",    179L,     79L
    )
)
```

Is there a way to plot the Height and Weight columns using `ggdensity()`. I am trying to make multiple density plots of each columns (Height and Weight) of each data frames but failed to do it.

Some codes I tried:

```
make_hist <- function(x){
  ggdensity(data, x)
}
plots <- lapply(df_list, make_hist)

r <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  ggdensity(data, x)
```

I even tried using imap but could not figure out the proper syntax for ggdensity and wrap it with imap() function or lapply().

Really sorry for this basic question and I hope someone could explain me the answer.

Comment: In the `make_hist` function, what is `data` parameter

Comment: A density plot is a univariate plot. What do you mean when you say you want to make a density plot using height and height exactly? How many plots are you expecting in the output?

Comment: according to ggdensity() documentation, it should be the dataframe.

Comment: @MrFlick, I am trying to make 6 different plots, 2 for each data frame in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop over the 'df_list', create the density plots for both 'Height' and 'Weight', then flatten the nested list (`do.call(c`) and use `ggarrange` to plot the elements in the `list` by specifying the `nrow` and `ncol`

```
library(ggpubr)
plots <- lapply(df_list, function(x) ggdensity(x, c("Height", "Weight")))
plots1 <- do.call(c, plots)
ggarrange(plotlist = plots1, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! So every time I want to run a function, I just need to bind the column names?

Comment: The `x` is `variable to be drawn.` which can be a single column name or a vector of ones, whereas the `y` is by default `..density..`